# Define Shortcut Keys by user (add or edit by user in web app)?

Tags: node.js, angular, web-applications

I have a web app create with angular 7.0 and Nodejs. I want to add a shortcut engine (user customizable) like Microsoft Word that user can add or edit or modify default shortcut keys for some function in this app. is there any code or tips for doing like this?

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an answer here but I do my best to stay away from packages unless I'm ready to do a deep-dive on what type of code I would be adding to my project.

Here is the Angular/JavaScript way to trigger functions on keyboard events.

```
@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event']) keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key === 27 || event.key === 13) {
        // console.log(event.key);
    }
}
```

I typically use [keycode.info](https://keycode.info/) or logging key presses to find my key numbers.

**Pseudo code based on comment question regarding user-specific key bindings.**

mock user object saved in database

```
user {
    ...
    bindings{
        featureOne: 27 // key chosen by user for featureOne
        featureTwo: 13 // key chosen by user for featureTwo
    }
}
```

Then you can refer to those choices in the listener

```
if (event.keyCode === user.bindings.featureOne) {
   // trigger featureOne
}
```

Comment: How user can define shortcut for myself for specific function?

Comment: You would need to save their preferences as part of their user object. Then the listener would become dynamic, listening for THEIR key events. I'll add some pseudo code for that.

Comment: can you recommend some demo or example link?

Comment: This may be rather large to setup as an example because of user-chosen key bindings. It's custom and I do not know of a library or package that could do this out-of-the-box. Do you have a developer to help you add the user choices?

Comment: `e.which` and `e.keyCode` are both deprecated. `e.key` or `e.code` should be used instead, which also make the code easier to understand. Just keep in mind some old browsers used some non-standard codes, so left is usually `'LeftArrow'` and right is `'RightArrow'`, but on IE and Legacy Edge they would be `'Left'` and `'Right'` instead. Also, take a look at https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon! 

Answer (score -1):

I guess [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-keyboard-shortcuts) suits your needs !

Comment: How user can define shortcut for myself for specific function? I get surprized ! this is wrong I think

Comment: You have an [example here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-keyboard-shortcuts#methods) You can store the user preference in localStorage or in a database if your user is logged-in, I don't know how you're planning to store the custom keybinds preferences. You create a user interface so your user is able to set its keybinds, you store them, then each time the user comes on your app, you load its preferences and follow the package documentation.